# Ember integration test fails after click event

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I have this integration test:

```
test('can change chord text', function(assert) {
  this.render(hbs`{{chart-editor-chord chord=chord}}`);
  this.$().click();
  assert.ok(!!this.$('.chord-input').length);
});
```

but the assertion fails, the component template looks like this:

```
<div {{action 'changeChord'}} class="measure-chord chord-big">
    {{#if chord.editing}}
        <input type="text" value="{{chord.name}}" class="chord-input">
    {{else}}
        {{chord.name}}
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

and the component code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    changeChord() {
        this.chord.set('editing', true);
    }
  }
});
```

I'm updating the `chord` model in the `changeChord()` action and it does work if I test in the browser, but the integration test fails. So, does this change in the model have to be rendered synchronously to the template? I tried using wait() in the test but that doesn't make a difference. So how should I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm trying to create a twiddle for you, I found three things:

1. Where do you create `chord` mock in your test?
2. You are not sending event to the correct html component. Use `this.$('.measure-chord')` or `this.$('.chord-big')`.
3. Instead of `this.chord.set` you should use `this.get('chord').set`. Actually `Ember.set(this, 'chord.isEditing', ...)` is even better.

And bonus: You don't need a `div` wrapper, component does this for you.

twiddles:

1. [working copy](https://ember-twiddle.com/517e36b719eb6e1913ef98c91726f52d/dc90fe20f1ae4d26a2aeb5b2067f4dbd273b6bec)
2. [without div](https://ember-twiddle.com/517e36b719eb6e1913ef98c91726f52d/96b90124c54f5a7a264b9cc17719c2f2df4c8505?openFiles=tests.integration.components.chart-editor-chord-test.js%2C)

Comment: Thanks! How stupid of me to miss the `.measure-chord` class in the jQuery selector... I thought I was missing something on a deeper level. Why is `Ember.set(this, 'chord.isEditing', ...)` even better? `this.get('chord').set` looks nicer in my opinion. And what do you mean with the `div` wrapper? In case I don't need to put any attributes on it?

Comment: @rednaw In some cases, or some tests you may want to mock the `chord` object. When `chord` is no more an Ember Object, `this.set` will not work, but `Ember.set` will.

Comment: @rednaw for your second question, have a look at [second twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/517e36b719eb6e1913ef98c91726f52d/96b90124c54f5a7a264b9cc17719c2f2df4c8505?openFiles=tests.integration.components.chart-editor-chord-test.js%2C). This is a `tagless-component` example. You can of course have attributes via `attributeBindings`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your click helper is clicking the div that your component.js controls instead of the initial div in your template. If you specify the div in your click helper it should work:

```
this.$('.measure-chord').click();
```

Comment: @ykaragol thanks, that's what happens when doing this on a phone ;-)